# Is it prudent to use HTML5 elements considering older browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser, element

I'm thinking of things like `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<article>`, `<section>` and the HTML5 doctype.

Is there any benefit to designing pages that way now? How will older browsers see them? Can they be validated?

I'm just not sure how backwards compatible these things are.

Comment: Google stopped supporting IE6 for gmail; it's time we moved on from older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a couple questions in your post:

> Is there any benefit to designing pages [using HTML5] now?

## yes

Using the new semantic web, you gain semantics. You give meaning to your data, which can then be made to do wonderous things.

> How will older browsers see them?

### It depends on the browser

The HTML spec says that non-standard HTML elements should be ignored, as if they were never in the source to begin with (unless something tells them otherwise). For most of the conforming browsers (read: FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome) you have to give HTML5 elements a display style before they will be shown:

```
section, header, footer, nav, article
{
  display: block;
}
```

Just remember, this relies on the browser actually conforming to specification, which some older browsers *cough* IE *cough* didn't do <sub>(at times I wonder if the IE dev team ever **read** any of the HTML specs)</sub>.

> Can they be validated?

### sort of...

The HTML5 spec isn't finalized yet, but there are already a number of online HTML5 validators that are available already.

Comment: +1 for "at times I wonder if the IE dev team ever read any of the HTML specs"

Answer (score 6):

A great way of ensuring backwards compatibility is to use something like modernizr, its a javascript file which tells you which html5/css3 features the user's browser supports, and this allows you to design your code in a way that it will degrade gracefully, or just use different rules for different browsers (for example, make a class which uses border-radius for browsers which support it, and a separate one with image based corner rounding for browsers which do not support that property.

[Modernizr site](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Comment: +1, but I edited your link-text to give some idea where the link goes, and why it's useful. Hopefully you don't mind? (if you do, I'm sorry for stepping on your toes!) =)

Answer (score 2):

It can be worthwhile for the reasons mentioned in the other responses, but there are a few issues to bear in mind:

- As mentioned elsewhere, browsers that don't understand the new elements need to have display: block; added to the style sheet
- pre IE 9 doesn’t allow you to style unknown elements so you need to use a JavaScript hack. See [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/) for more information on how to do this
- The BlackBerry browser (pre BlackBerry OS6) also doesn't allow them to be styled. I don't know of any work arounds for this. If this matters to you depends on how much your site is focused on mobile and if you have a separate mobile site. The BlackBerry browser is a popular mobile browser however, and it will take a while for the new BlackBerry OS with their WebKit browser to get a significant share of BlackBerry devices.
- Screen readers also don’t know about these new elements. It is recommended to double them up with the equivalent ARIA roles until support is ubiquitous. See [HTML5, ARIA Roles, and Screen Readers](http://www.accessibleculture.org/research/html5-aria/)  for more information.

I don’t know any drawbacks in using the HTML5 doctype. I believe this is fully safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, yes - many browsers already implement support for parts of HTML 5, or the features commonly associated with it, and the way some of them are, you won't break anything even if you did introduce them to a browser that didn't grok it.

As always, you should use proper feature detection, rather than all-encompassing browser detection, to determine what's available - it's less vulnerable to broken User-Agent strings and the like.

There's an excellent guide, [Dive Into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/), which basically discusses this very point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, html5 is a universal standard and as such most(excluding IE) support it heavly. Also, you can put flash inside the video tags incase video is not supported and you can setup a library like jquery as a backup if html5 is not supported.